# R incrementing by decimal value does not return expected value

Tags: r

I am writing a function in R that requires me to increment a counter by 0.05.   When I condition on the value of the counter I am getting told that the value is not what it appears.

Example:

Set the counter to 0

> cntr <- 0; cntr;

```
[1] 0
```

Increment counter by 0.05 and test

> cntr <- cntr + 0.05; cntr;
>       [1] 0.05

```
> cntr == 0.05
[1] TRUE
```

So far, so good.  But after a couple more iterations the following happens:

```
> cntr <- cntr + 0.05; cntr;
[1] 0.1
> cntr == 0.1
[1] TRUE
> cntr <- cntr + 0.05; cntr;
[1] 0.15
> cntr == 0.15
[1] FALSE
```

What is happening, and why?  The value returned for cntr is 0.15 but it is not equal to this value?
Further investigation reveals this:

```
> cntr < 0.1500000000000001
[1] TRUE
> cntr < 0.15000000000000001
[1] FALSE
```

and

> round(cntr, 2) == 0.15
>       [1] TRUE

Am I misunderstanding something, or is there something I am not seeing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: This is [FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `isTRUE(all.equal(cntr, x))`, where x is 0.1, 0.05, etc. instead. Your tests are failing because of floating point rounding errors. `all.equal` tests equality up to that error. Check out Circle 1 in [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for other examples of where this might trip you up.

Comment: Why do you need `isTRUE`? Wouldn't `all.equal(cntr, x)` alone give you `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: @SachaEpskamp: `all.equal` returns a message when it is not `TRUE`.

Comment: Ah yes I see it now in the help page, that's why it never worked for me :D

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had seen floating point issues before with dividing and multiplying, its the first I've seen with addition.

Answer (score 3):

One other approach to this could be to use an integer and to increment by `5`. When you need to use the incremented value, divide by 100.

The problem you have illustrated is due to how decimal values are stored in computer programs when using a binary format; it is not a problem specific to `R`. You can read more about the reasons for this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Answer (score 3):

In a broader sense, you look like you are pretty new to R programming, and I want to ask why you are trying to use a counter. In general, R discourages the use of loops, especially loops with counters in them. If you are using a loop with a counter, it is likely that you can vectorize your function to improve the efficiency of your code.

Comment: Yes, I am fairly new to R.  I have a dataset that I need to analyze in bins.  There is a field in the data that takes the values 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, ..., 1 .  What I was trying to do is use the subset command to return the set where that field equals my cntr. 

I started by trying something like this:  
range <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05)
for(i in range){
     newset <- subset(originalset, field == i)
    <rest of code>
}

which through various methods turned into:

cntr = 0
for(i in 1:21){
      newset <- subset(originalset, field == cntr)
      cntr <- cntr + 0.05
      ...
}

Comment: If it is already binned, check out the `by` function to do by-group processing.